# Using Paste to collapse a vector in R

Tags: r, paste

I have a data frame `mynames` of a single column that i wish to convert to a character string. The aim being to select the names of columns in another dataset based on the items in this string. An example of the data is below

```
X
A
B
C
```

I tried using the code below to paste it all together using the following code

```
paste(mynames, sep="", collapse="")
```

However that produces the out put below which is far from ideal

"c(\"A\", \"B\", \"C\",..........

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"))
st <- paste(dat$x,collapse="")
st
```

prints

```
> st
[1] "abc"
```

and to make it comma-separated:

```
> st <- paste(dat$x,collapse=",")
> st
[1] "a,b,c"
```

Comment: Thanks @rbm, if i want to seperate it via a comma i tried something like this `paste(dat$x, collapse="", sep = ",")` but it seems to ignore the seperator requirement. Do you know why?