# using paste to collapse multiple vectors

Tags: r, paste

I know that using paste I can use `collapse` to put a "+" between all the elements.  For example as described here: [Using Paste to collapse a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497289/using-paste-to-collapse-a-vector-in-r).  It works great here:

```
a <- paste( c( "one", "two") , collapse=" + " )
b <- paste( c( "3", "4") , collapse=" + " )
```

But when I try to paste together two vectors with a "+" between them it pastes the elements without the separator

```
paste( a , b , collapse = " + ")
```

I want "one + two + 3 + 4"

Comment: I'd recommend experimenting with the difference between the collapse and sep arguments—read up on the docs and do a little trial & error. In your second step of pasting a and b, what you're doing isn't quite the same as in the first step, so you'll need a different argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need option `sep=`.

```
paste(a, b, sep=" + ")
# [1] "one + two + 3 + 4"
```